# how to apply overflow x in row class

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

how to apply Row scroll overflow on x-axis direction for col-5, col-6, and col-7

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">col 1</div>
          <div class="col-4">col 2</div>
          <div class="col-4">col 3</div>
          <div class="col-4">col 4</div>
          <div class="col-4">col 5</div>
          <div class="col-4">col 6</div>
          <div class="col-4">col 7</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a specific class descriptor for those columns to give them additional styling

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">col 1</div>
      <div class="col-4">col 2</div>
      <div class="col-4">col 3</div>
      <div class="col-4">col 4</div>
      <div class="col-4 xoverflow">col 5</div>
      <div class="col-4 xoverflow">col 6</div>
      <div class="col-4 xoverflow">col 7</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**app.css**

```
.xoverflow {
   overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use this:

```
.col-4:nth-child(5), .col-4:nth-child(6), .col-4:nth-child(7) {
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
```